# Calculate (A / B) mod C

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

someone told me:

`(A / B) MOD C = ((A) MOD (B * C)) / B`

Is that right?

I have tried some testcases and it turned out to be so

Please prove or give me a counter-example if it's false

Comment: Please indicate what test cases you tried.  You seem to be treating "mod" as an operator (as in a programming language) where mathematicans will generally treat "mod" as an equivalence relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true. When taking $\frac{A}{B}$ as a division, the property holds.

**However** it is important to note that if $bx = a \pmod{c}$ and you are solving for integers $x$, it is not true that $x = \frac{a}{b} \pmod{c}$.

For example, if I wanted to find all integers $x$ such that $2x = 1 \pmod{3}$ we are not searching for all $x = \frac{1}{2} \pmod{3}$. This would imply that $x$ is not an integer of course.

Other than that, $\frac{A}{B} \pmod{C} = \frac{A}{B} - kC$ for some integer $k$. Then, we can multiply the expression by $\frac{B}{B}$ to get $\frac{A - kCB}{B}$ and the numerator is just $A \pmod{BC}$.